# How to, in an ASP.MVC view, specify a strongly-typed model data that's defined in a library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Model class that's defined in a library.  In a strongly-typed ASP.MVC view, I would like to specify that view.  Is this possible and if so, what is the syntax?

If the Model class is in the same assembly, it would just look like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyWebApp.Model.MyData>" %>
```

So if I'm guessing, would it be something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyWebApp.Model.MyData>, MyExternalLib" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax would simply be:

```
<%@ Page Title="" 
         Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
         Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyWebApp.Model.MyData>" 
%>
```

But you must ensure that your external library appears in the `assemblies` section of your web.config.

And it could even look like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" 
         Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
         Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyData>" 
%>
```

if the `MyWebApp.Model` namespace is added to the `namespaces` section of your web.config